# Help selecting rechargeable batteries for 3W 1A handheld lantern

Tags: led, batteries, battery-operated

Salutes. I want to build a handheld lantern with a 3W 3V LED and the best I have is a 9V battery and I don't want to buy dozens of 1,5V, 9V batteries nor use a car battery (for a **handheld** lantern). Despite the LED asking for 3V which I could adjust for, the real problem is the 1A I should feed the LED with, which would blackout common batteries in seconds due to their *Maximum Continuous Discharge Current* property, according to [this basic battery guide](http://web.mit.edu/evt/summary_battery_specifications.pdf). I confirm that with a misconnection I once made and [this site](http://www.newtoncbraga.com.br/index.php/duvidas-dos-internautas/5723-corrente-de-pilhas-comuns-duv373.html) that once told me 9V batteries have a nominal current ourput around 12mA, although I know one of mine can stand stable providing 80mA.

According to [that same second site](http://www.newtoncbraga.com.br/index.php/duvidas-dos-internautas/5723-corrente-de-pilhas-comuns-duv373.html), looks like I should use around 9 "D-batteries" to stay in a safe zone, but I wanted to know how many times I could force the reccommended current *("Corrente recomendada (mA)", in the referred website)* while maintaining a basically stable discharge.

I'm new to bulk converters and I thought maybe I could lower a 9V battery voltage and increase the *Maximum Continuous Discharge Current* of the battery, but bulks also dissipate power and the idea seems awkward, it seems better to use lower voltage batteries instead (but expensive).

I could of course limit the current to 0,5 or 0,75A to ease the design, but I actually wanted to use two diodes instead of "half". So am I forced to opt for a wired power source?

Comment: This project is for fun. No worries if you can't help. I respect your time if you have other priorities.

Comment: Start by spending some time studying how flashlights currently only the market actually work. What you've posted is not really viable, you need to invest some real time in researching what is.  At present, you do not have a specific, answerable question within the mission of this site.  You may conclude it is better to simply buy a a flashlight meeting your needs... its not necessarily something that makes a very good DIY project.

Comment: 3W is too much for a battery operated handheld lantern. Think about 1W, instead. For powering it, google about _"6V 908"_ batteries. And think about lithium, too: google for _"18650 lithium"_. And (pelamordedeus) make a favour to yourself and be very careful with this site that you linked: it is full of outdated information that can misguide a newbie. Most of the content of that site are the works of Mr. Newton C. Braga in 70's to 90's (he is somewhat a kind of Brazilian Forrest Mims); and I must add that Mr. Braga has a unforgivable fondness for 555 IC.

Comment: 3W is a bit much to ask of a little 9V  my 3W flashlight uses and 18650 li-ion cell

Comment: 1A absolutely will not "black out" a quality alkaline 1.5V cell AA, C or D.  This C size cell will give you 30 minutes at 1A discharge:    https://rexel-cdn.com/Products/Energizer/E93.pdf?i=0495ECF4-4CFD-432A-8598-278C0A7B0E0D     (Even longer if you can tolerate a lower voltage that you call it "dead" at)

Comment: The problem with using a 9V is that it's actually 6 small "AAAA" size batteries in series, so the internal resistance of each adds up.   A fresh alkaline has about 1/4 ohm resistance, so in a 9V, thats 1.5 ohm resistance right out of the gate.   9V is frankly probably the worst possible choice you could make for this project.  (Well,  a lithum coin cell would be even worse, but....)

Answer (score 0):

Lithium or the much safer LiFePO4 would be appropriate here, certainly not non-rechargeable D cells. There are larger cells than 18650 ... a couple of 32650 cells might be more appropriate.

1 LiFePO4 cell (3.2V) covers a range of 3.6V (very briefly), 3.3 to 3.1 (most of the discharge time) ad can be used down to 2.5 but there's no point going below 2.8V. Unfortunately this probably crosses the voltage range of your LED so you either need a buck-boost converter, or (probably better) 2 cells in series and a buck converter.